# How to keep the connection open to websocket server?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I have the following code, that does not keep the connection open to the websocket server:

```
import akka.Done
import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorLogging, Props}
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.StatusCodes
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.ws.{Message, TextMessage, WebSocketRequest}
import akka.stream.{ActorMaterializer, Materializer}
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Flow, Keep, Sink, Source}

import scala.concurrent._
import scala.util.{Failure, Success}

object WsActor {
  def props: Props = Props(new WsActor)
}

final class WsActor extends Actor with ActorLogging {

  import com.sweetsoft.WsConnector._

  implicit val materializer: Materializer = ActorMaterializer()
  implicit val ec: ExecutionContextExecutor = context.system.dispatcher
  implicit val actor = context.system

  // Future[Done] is the materialized value of Sink.foreach,
  // emitted when the stream completes
  private val incoming: Sink[Message, Future[Done]] =
  Sink.foreach[Message] {
    case message: TextMessage.Strict =>
      println(message.text)
    case _ =>
      println("Unknown messages.")
  }

  //private val outgoing: Source[Message, Promise[Option[Message]]] =
  //  Source.maybe[Message]

  //  val flow: Flow[Message, Message, Promise[Option[Message]]] =
  //    Flow.fromSinkAndSourceMat(incoming, Source.maybe[Message])(Keep.right)


  log.info("Websocket actor started.")

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case Initialized =>
      log.info("Initialization to receive messages via stream.")
      sender() ! Ack
    case Completed =>
      log.info("Streams completed.")
      sender() ! Ack
    case Msg(value) =>

      val replyTo = sender()
      val flow: Flow[Message, Message, Promise[Option[Message]]] =
        Flow.fromSinkAndSourceMat(incoming, Source.single(TextMessage(value)).concatMat(Source.maybe[Message])(Keep.right))(Keep.right)

      val (upgradeResponse, _) =
        Http().singleWebSocketRequest(WebSocketRequest("ws://127.0.0.1:7000/ws"), flow.mapAsync(4)(msg => Future(msg)))

      upgradeResponse.flatMap { upgrade =>
        if (upgrade.response.status == StatusCodes.SwitchingProtocols) {
          Future.successful(Done)
        } else {
          throw new RuntimeException(s"Connection failed: ${upgrade.response.status}")
        }
      }.onComplete {
        case Success(_) =>
          replyTo ! Ack
          log.info("Done")
        case Failure(ex) => log.error(ex.getMessage)
      }

    case Failed(ex) =>
      log.info(s"Stream failed with ${ex.getMessage}.")
  }

}
```

So every time, when a message is received, it will close the connection and open a new connection for the next request.
The question is, how can I keep the connection open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Http().webSocketClientFlow` in stead of `Http().singleWebSocketRequest`

`Http().webSocketClientFlow` will give you a Flow `Flow[Message, Message, Future[WebSocketUpgradeResponse]]`

This will not create a new connection every time.

You should declare it in the companion object, so every instance of the class can use the same connection.

First declare your actor system for entire application in a separate package.

```
object ActorEssentials {
        implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem("test")
}
```

Then you can declare the following

```
object WsActor {
  import ActorEssentials._
  def props: Props = Props[WsActor]
  val flow = Http()(actorSystem).webSocketClientFlow(...) 
}
```

Comment: `You should declare it in the companion object, so every instance of the class can use the same connection.` I am still learning Scala, could you please provide an example that?

Comment: Like you have declared `def props=new Props(new WsActor)` in `object WsActor {}`. You should include the `Http().webSocketClientFlow` in companion object. In that way it will be instantiated only once.

Comment: Another thing is you should change `def props = new Props(new WsActot)` to `def props=Props[WsActor]`

Comment: I can not share `Http().webSocketClientFlow` because of `def apply()(implicit system: ActorSystem): HttpExt = super.apply(system)` as you can see, it expects an `ActorSystem`

Comment: You can pass actorSystem as an argument to the method. I have edited my answer. Please let me know in case of any question.

Comment: Then it will not share the instance of the flow. Every time, when I call a new flow, it will return a new flow.

Comment: I have made another edit to my answer. Will it solve your issue ?

Comment: Awesome,thanks a lot for your help. I appreciate a lot.